# How to call a Parent class method from child class instance having super

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to do something like this but getting error.
I can't find any help in official documents and i thought this would be simple as calling a parent method.

"ERROR TypeError: childA.getChildOfType is not a function"

```
export class Parent
{
    constructor(public type: string)
    {}

    public getChildOfType = (type: string) =>
    {
        if(this[type] && this[type].length > 0) return this[type];
        return null;
    }
}


export class ChildA extends Parent
{
    Plants = ['Amaryllis', 'African Violet', 'Bird Of Paradise'];
    
    constructor(public type: string)
    {
        super(type);
    }
}

export class ChildB extends Parent
{
    Animals = ['Monkey', 'Tiger', 'Mouse'];
    
    constructor(public type: string)
    {
        super(type);
    }
}

const childA = new ChildA('Plants');
const childB = new ChildB('Animals');

console.log(childA.getChildOfType('Plants'));
console.log(childA.getChildOfType('Animals'));
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oG8C+BuAUJg9AKggA8wB7AJ2DxygGMAbAQwGcmoAFBsiAO2E2UxQhtEtybAyAVxrByACjCSARnQCWNKKEgAuWPACUg4WmzCoileqgBzCMADCAC1V0AJgHkAZnEhQkcrQhdcTJVbmt9PwA+IyEBMzNVTwDnJgBtQIBdKAAyHM1UjPhMgDo6HmtgRygoqAAGSK5gSTJuAtV0rKwE4SaWtu5JOjpu4VRMcdwCYnJKanpmVicXVwBBKCJgHldWDi5eflj2Rl5WJDSAcgANC4AaKAuATQvM0aEjmlEQ6VkyBWU1BpArofBBDGZ4j0oExJJA-oF9G8oONJvgiKQKFRaIwWFBlm4AEIbQhbbg7dicHh8SFCVbcVQAWwYdDOUEuAFk7g8YC8kR8vhIfvILIDNPAQQYjjSEjC4QEDEiUdhPmJgLRnG51khuBAAO54jVrOQXNgnYBMC6IzAq8TqlZE7V6g32410xnMi1Wm0kcplEjWOQ0Q2rEq2ByGryg42mhinS1er4+iB+gNB+2huz4jzeeCu+lMlnx9BAA

Comment: ^^ I don't get the error you describe. I do get *other* errors (type errors at compile time), but not what you describe (which is a runtime error).

Comment: This was just an example. I have a similar code and this was just to explain the context, what i trying to do.
What i want is the array should be returned based on the type passed.
I have changed the type (not required) to string

Comment: I can see this works in the playground. I can see the log. Not sure why it is not working in my code. Thanks anyways

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, with all the necessary code in the question, and ideally also a link to the playground demonstrating the error.

Answer (score -1):

try something like :

```
Parent.prototype.getChildOfType = (type: string) =>
    {
        if(this[type] && this[type].length > 0) return this[type];
        return null;
    }
```